# Почему два одинаковых класса работают по-разному?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня в программе есть два класса которые отвечают за получение списков входящих и исходящих сообщений. У каждого из этих классов есть адаптеры которые используются моим `RecyclerView`. Я пытаюсь использовать для работы `Navigation Drawer`, в котором при выборе меню выбирается определенный класс и посылается запрос на список нужных мне сообщений. Проблема состоит в том, что вроде-бы эти два класса идентичны, отличаются только параметры запроса, но вот работает и посылается запрос только с класса полученных сообщений, а на отправленные мне выводит ошибку:

```
No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

вот эти два класса. 
Класс полученных сообщений и его адаптер:

```
public class Received extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_received, container, false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_res);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        received();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_2);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        received();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void received() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        adapter = null;

        sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("access_token", 0);
        String a_token = sp.getString("access_token", "");

        final APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.getInMess("Bearer " + a_token, 0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<MessageArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull Response<MessageArray> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
                    adapter = new MessageAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("access_token_expired")) {
                            updateToken();

                        } else if (errorBody.string().contains("invalid_token")) {
                            updateToken();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {


            }
        });
    }

    public void updateToken() {


    }


    public void logOut() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

адаптер:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageHolder> {
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id";

    MessageAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new MessageHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageHolder holder, int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());

        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println(dateString);
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String timeString = timeFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println(timeString);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString+"  " +timeString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyIncomingMessageId, message.getId());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class MessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

        MessageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        }
    }
}
```

класс для отправленных сообщений и его адаптер:

```
public class Sent extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    private boolean isVisible;
    private boolean isStarted;


    SharedPreferences sp;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sent, container, false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_sen);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_1);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        sent();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        isStarted = true;
        if (isVisible) {
            sent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
        if (isVisible && isStarted) {
            sent();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void sent() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        adapter = null;

        sp = Objects.requireNonNull(context).getSharedPreferences("access_token", 0);


        String a_token = sp.getString("access_token", "");
        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.getInMess("Bearer " + a_token, 1, 1).enqueue(new Callback<MessageArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull Response<MessageArray> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getMessages();
                    adapter = new MessageAdapter2(messageArrayList, getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);


                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {

                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("access_token_expired")) {
                            updateToken();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void updateToken() {


    }


    public void logOut() {
            }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {

        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

его адаптер:

```
public class MessageAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter2.SenderHolder> {
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;
    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id"; // для исходящих

    MessageAdapter2(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new SenderHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SenderHolder holder, int position) {
        final Message message = messageList.get(position);

        holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());

        DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault());
        String isoString = message.getDate();
        try {
            Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println(dateString);
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            String timeString = timeFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println(timeString);
            holder.tvDate.setText(dateString + "  " + timeString);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MessageShow.class);
                intent.putExtra(MessageAdapter.class.getSimpleName() + keyOutboundMessageId, message.getId());
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Long pressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate, text;

        SenderHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
            tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

пример ответа с сервера на полученные сообщения:

```
 {"next_url": null, "count": 3, "messages": [{"id": 2409277, "attach": false, "can_delete": true, "date": "2018-07-25T16:49:13+02:00", "sender_name": "Poltava - Amina Al-Shahoud", "subject": "\u0441\u0430\u0432\u0441\u0432\u0430 \u0432\u044b\u043c\u0430\u0432", "new": 0}, {"id": 2409276, "attach": false, "can_delete": true, "date": "2018-07-25T16:48:48+02:00", "sender_name": "Poltava - Amina Al-Shahoud", "subject": "\u043f\u0440\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0434", "new": 0}, {"id": 2407651, "attach": false, "can_delete": true, "date": "2018-07-19T15:46:34+02:00", "sender_name": "Poltava - Amina Al-Shahoud", "subject": "AW: Neu registrierte/r Bewerber/in Andrew Horoshko (ID 9533961) in Ihrer Vermittlungsdokumentation", "new": 0}], "previous_url": null}
```

честно говоря, я уже три дня сижу и не смог найти причину. Меня классы  модели, на полученные данные, менял название классов, думал может где-то два одинаковых названия, создавал все по новой, но мне ничего не помогло. Может кто-то заметит причину почему у меня не выводятся сообщения и даже не посылается запрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `onCreateView` первого фрагмента вызывается `received();`
В `onCreateView` второго фрагмента **не** вызывается `sent();`

---

P.S. Если два класса идентичны - значит второй лишний и можно использовать один в обоих случаях. То что различается заменить полями, конкретные значения которым задавать при создании класса.

Comment: по поводу вашего P.S - я все думаю как это сделать, но пока мои попытки соединить два класса не увенчались успехом